# Sorting with different date fields

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I have a tricky SQL question. I am working with posts that can be sent or scheduled. Here is the structure:

```
----------------
- Posts        -
----------------
- id           -
- sent_at      -
- scheduled_at -
- created_at   -
----------------
```

- A post can be sent without being scheduled.
- A scheduled post will be sent at the scheduled_at date. At this point the sent_at date will be equal to the scheduled_at date
- Some posts are just created, with no sent, or scheduled date
- All posts have a created_at date

**Examples of possible data:**

```
P1: {scheduled_at: NULL, sent_at: NULL, created_at: T}
P2: {scheduled_at: NULL, sent_at: T, created_at: T}
P3: {scheduled_at: T, sent_at: T, created_at: T}
P4: {scheduled_at: T+n, sent_at: NULL, created_at: T}
P5: {scheduled_at: T+n, sent_at: T+n, created_at: T}
```

**What I want to do:**

I want to get all posts ordered by a different attribute depending on the situation

- `created_at` for P1 and P2
- `scheduled_at` for P3, P4, and P5

I tried different variations of ORDER conditions but I can't get anything to work for all the cases. I hope this all makes sense. I can provide more details if it doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using coalesce:

```
select * from foo
order by coalesce(created_at, scheduled_at)
```

Answer (score 2):

In P1 and P2 `scheduled_at` is `NULL` so this is the only case which should be ordered by `created_at`. 
So you can use:
`ORDER BY CASE WHEN scheduled_at IS NULL THEN created_at ELSE scheduled_at END`

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working. Can you really use CASE with mysql?

Comment: Sorry forgot the END clause, try now.

Comment: +1 It works now, thanks! I'll try the coalesce solution as well and see the one more fitted for the situation